# How to implement the system camera app's shrink animation effect?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation, camera

The system's camera app has a UI effect. After taking a photo, it will show the animation, which is the photo shrink and move to the left bottom corner.

How can I implement the effect in my app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the view that you're trying to shrink call something like this code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    // self is the view in this case
    // if you call this from the controller, use self.view
    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, smallWidth, smallHeight);
    self.bounds = CGRectOffset(self.bounds, amountToMoveX, amountToMoveY);
}];
```

This might not be exactly the animation you're looking for but it should give you a good start.